# Android handwriting recognition

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, handwriting-recognition

I need to analyse android handwriting recognition SDK's. Can anybody tell me what SDK's are available on the market. I've found [MyScript](http://www.visionobjects.com/en/myscript/about-myscript/) from VisionObjects, but I cant find any download link from the SDK, because I need to test to see the accuracy.

Comment: have you tried tesseract library ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working for MyScript, you can try online recognition using the Web Services here : https://dev.myscript.com/developer-program/register/ and if you only want to try the MyScript accuracy, you can try our webdemos http://webdemo.myscript.com/

Edit: Vision Objects company was renamed to MyScript, so I've edit links

Comment: yeah um... I can't do anything from the web services link, that's just a login page.

Comment: hello, I see that webservice translate handwrite-to-text very perfect, how can I do the same in android :)

Comment: Hi, you can find development kit for Android at [https://dev.myscript.com/](https://dev.myscript.com/)