# How to integrate Google Handwriting Input keyboard in own app?

Tags: android, google-input-tools

Is there any way to integrate "**Google Handwriting Input**" tool in your own app.

I have checked the links below

1. http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2015/04/google-handwriting-app-for-android.html
2. [Android handwriting recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415226/android-handwriting-recognition)

I have checked 2nd link but I have found another way ("google handwriting input"). Is it possible  to integrate **Google Handwriting** Input to our own app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android handwriting recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415226/android-handwriting-recognition) and  [Handwriting recognition API's for android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063345/handwriting-recognition-apis-for-android-applications)

Comment: Hi Anantha Raju c- I have already check myscript(2 option). I have already defined in my post .But i will try with google keyboard (1 Link)option in own app.If not possible then 2 way apply.

Answer (score -2):

Just install the [google handwriting app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.handwriting.ime&hl=en&rdid=com.google.android.apps.handwriting.ime), follow the steps mentioned in that app, then the handwriting option will be enabled in the device. 
Hence, when any input get focused, just choose the keyboard option and set it to
 "Google handwriting input"