# Handwriting gesture recognition for multiple characters android

Tags: android, gesture, handwriting-recognition

I have implemented handwriting gestures for android character recognition for a single character as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JToMP.png).

But i want to read multiple characters at a single time, .i.e **Android**. I am able to read a single character by the following implementation. But, I need help to recognize a complete word like **Android** at the same time.

My implementation so far is shown below.
         GestureLibrary mLibrary;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!mLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }

    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

    if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
        String result = predictions.get(0).name;

        if ("a".equalsIgnoreCase(result))
        {
            ////Toast.makText(this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+"a");
        }
   }
}
```

Before putting my question, I want everyone there to know that I have checked and read all the questions and answers on stackoverflow regarding this question.

Comment: You want to read multiple characters at a single time, but you can only draw (i.e. gesture) one character at a time (this library is not geared for cursive).  It sounds like you think it recognizes the character by looking at the pixels in the image after you draw.  That's not how it works.  It tracks the actual motion of your finger on the screen and tries to determine what character you are drawing.  Gesture recognition vs. character recognition.  Motion vs. image.  You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14415226/4504191

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I  want to read multiple characters at a single time. I got your answer. I have already visited the link you sent to me. Myscript library is not free and requires much money which they deserve. My question is, is there any way that I can make my own handwriting recognition library. Or, is there any library which would be free to use. Or any link, document or anything which would lead me to the solution.

Comment: Optical handwriting recognition is a difficult problem to solve.  There are top research scientists at places like Google working on it.  I don't think you'll be able to find any freely available libraries for Android.

Comment: There should be a way to do it, for sure. Like **MyScript** sdk. I just want to know the way out "MyScript" are using in their application. What technique they are using, so that it would help me on that.