# Integrate Google handwriting input keyboard directly in your android app

Tags: android, handwriting-recognition, google-input-tools

I am developing an android app which gets user handwriting on the screen and write that as a text in editText field of android. 
I have used gesture recognition before but that not gets too far as I have discussed in some of my other post. But that post didn't answered me well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039943/handwriting-gesture-recognition-for-multiple-characters-android).

So now, I want to use google handwriting input as my writing keyboard without installing their keyboard manually.
Inshort, all I need is to attach google's handwriting input keyboard to my app and use it as user installs my app on android device.
Is there any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am working at MyScript.

You can use an external library like MyScript iink. A example is available on [Github repo](https://github.com/MyScript/interactive-ink-examples-android).

The documentation is [available online](https://developer.myscript.com/docs/interactive-ink/1.0/overview/about/)

You can use this lib as an alternative to a keyboard by displaying a writing zone where your user will be able to write on it.